# Xcode Swift 3 Timer Error

Tags: swift, xcode, timer

This code had to be converted to Swift 3.

```
func checkIfCorrect (_ buttonPressed:Int) {
        if buttonPressed == playlist[numberOfTaps] {
            if numberOfTaps == playlist.count - 1 { // we have arrived at the last item of the playlist

                let time = DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: DispatchTime.now()) + Double(Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: { 
                        self.nextRound()
                })

                return
            }
```

The code returns an error that says "Cannot convert value of type 'DispatchTime' to expected argument type UInt64". What would be a good fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 it's much easier

For example a `DispatchTime` of a second from now is:

```
let time : DispatchTime = .now() + .seconds(1)
```

These other units are available, too:

- `.milliseconds()`
- `.microseconds()`
- `.nanoseconds()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of how expressive Swift 3 can be.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: { 
                    self.nextRound()
            })
```